# Is a normal subgroup normal in a normal group?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a normal ($T_4$) topological group, that is, every two disjoint closed sets of $G$ have disjoint open neighborhoods. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ that is normal too ($T_4$) with the induced subspace topology. Is $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$? That is, $\forall g \in H \, $, $ \, gH=Hg \ \ $?

This question came up as a pun and evolved into a sincere question to which I did not get a definitive answer.

Comment: More examples are metrizable groups, in which every subgroup is normal in the topological sense, but not necessarily in the algebra one. Furthermore note that every closed subspace of a normal space is again normal, so if the answer were yes it would imply that all closed subgroups are normal (in the algebra sense) which is clearly wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, take any group $G$ with a non-normal subgroup $H$ and equip $G$ with the discrete topology.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. Take *any* group $G$ endowed with the discrete metric and *any* non-normal (in the group-theoretical sense) subgroup $H$ of $G$. Then $H$ *is* normal with respect to the induced topology, but it is still a non-normal subgroup of $G$.